# Let $f : X \to Y$ be a bijective continuous function. Show that if $X$ is compact, then $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology

I'm studying for a topology exam and encountered the following problem:

> Let $f : X \to Y$ be a bijective continuous function. Show that if $X$ is compact, then $f$ is a homeomorphism.

I struggled to solve it, so I looked up Munkres and found the following theorem (Th 26.6):

> Let $f : X \to Y$ be a bijective continuous function. If $X$ is compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff, then $f$ is a homeomorphism.

This leads me to think that maybe the first statement is false. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the identity map $$\textrm{Id}:(\Bbb{R}, \tau_{\text{co-finite}})\to( \Bbb{R}, \tau_{indiscrete}) $$

Then $\textrm{Id}$ is a continuous bijection from the compact space but not a bi-continuous map.